# Combine Multiple Lists one by one

Tags: python

I have 3 lists and I would like to combine my three lists into another list with tuples or lists inside with these  three lists mixed, like this:

```
years = [2012,2013,2011,2014,2015]
sessions = ["AC", "AB"]
periods = ["I", "II", "III"]
```

I would like to know if there is a function or what is the most **Pythonic** way to do the next:

```
result = function(years,sessions,periods)
print result 

##  [(2012, "AC", "I"), (2012, "AC", "II"), (2012, "AC", "III"), (2012, "AB", "I")] and so on
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> years = [2012,2013,2011,2014,2015]
>>> sessions = ["AC", "AB"]
>>> periods = ["I", "II", "III"]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> list(product(years, sessions, periods))
[(2012, 'AC', 'I'), (2012, 'AC', 'II'), (2012, 'AC', 'III'), (2012, 'AB', 'I'), (2012, 'AB', 'II'), (2012, 'AB', 'III'), (2013, 'AC', 'I'), (2013, 'AC', 'II'), (2013, 'AC', 'III'), (2013, 'AB', 'I'), (2013, 'AB', 'II'), (2013, 'AB', 'III'), (2011, 'AC', 'I'), (2011, 'AC', 'II'), (2011, 'AC', 'III'), (2011, 'AB', 'I'), (2011, 'AB', 'II'), (2011, 'AB', 'III'), (2014, 'AC', 'I'), (2014, 'AC', 'II'), (2014, 'AC', 'III'), (2014, 'AB', 'I'), (2014, 'AB', 'II'), (2014, 'AB', 'III'), (2015, 'AC', 'I'), (2015, 'AC', 'II'), (2015, 'AC', 'III'), (2015, 'AB', 'I'), (2015, 'AB', 'II'), (2015, 'AB', 'III')]
```

Note that `product()` returns an iterable; I've just converted it to a list above for demonstration purposes, but you shouldn't do so unless you definitely need a list.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres No problem, glad I could help. It might behoove you to skim through `itertools` if you have time, since there are some very useful functions there.